# TFS 2015 - Build Configuration - Edit Build - Default Queue Drop Down

Tags: msbuild, tfs-2015

I have a new Team Project Collection called TBC1 and in that team project collection I have a team project called TP1. In TP1 I have checked-in a .Net web application built using VS 2015, the name of that project is Project1. I have created a build definition called BD1 for Project1.

The TFS Server is a local installation of TFS 2015 RTM. There are several separate build servers on our network.

Once the agent is installed on the separate build server, how do I make that agent accessible via the "Default Queue" drop down on the General Tab of the TFS Web UI Build Definition?

Update: I figured this out. When installing the agent on the build server you can put in the URL of the TFS server when prompted to do so. At that point you can choose a pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you configure the agent it will ask which pool you wish for the agent to be in.

```
C:\TEMP\vsoagent>ConfigureAgent.cmd
An existing configuration file was detected.  This will update the local agent s
ettings.  Do you want to also replace the server registration (default is N)?
Enter the name for this agent (default is myAgent)
Enter the URL for the Team Foundation Server (default is https://myvs.visual
studio.com)
Configure this agent against which agent pool? (default pool name is 'default')
```